# Sci-Fi cartoon including flowers with rejuvenation powers

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

I don't remember it very well, but there was a science-fiction 
cartoon from around the time period of 2009-2013 and it was about some weird flowers (I think from another planet, not sure) that had rejuvenation powers. There were also these 3 kids, that were actually adults, but rejuvenated using those flowers, who were the villains of the show. These kids used to drive a Jeep around the town.

In one episode, I remember that these flowers started to take over the city appearing everywhere, and I think they were dangerous for some reason, they could put people into a coma or something like that, but I'm also not sure about this.

Comment: What sort of animation are we talking about? Japanese animation? 3d animation? Regular western animation? Do you remember something more about characters or overall plot?